# Configuration parsing and verification utility for bioinformatics tools

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on my first Python library which provides different utilities for a set of bioinformatics tools. I am looking for feedback on this module I made for parsing configurations needed for each tool run.

To give a little more context, users are prompted with a text box to edit the default parameters that a tool runs with given a list of different acceptable values that each option may take on.

config.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    toolhelper.config
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    This module provides the needed functionality 
    for parsing and verifying user-inputted config files.
"""
import sys
import logging

PY2 = sys.version_info[0] == 2
if PY2:
    import ConfigParser
else:
    import configparser as ConfigParser


class Config(object):
    """This class implements config file parsing and validation.

    Methods: 
        ...

    Attributes:
        ...
    """
    def __init__(self, defaults,
                 value_map,
                 filename,
                 sections,
                 numericals=None,
                 allow_no_val=False):
        self.defaults = defaults
        self.value_map = value_map
        self.filename = filename
        self.sections = sections
        self.numericals = numericals
        self.settings = self._parse()
        self.allow_no_val = allow_no_val

    def _parse(self):
        """Builds dict from user-inputted config settings.

        Returns:
            Dictionary of config settings to be used for a tool run.
        """
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=self.allow_no_val)
        cfg = config.read(self.filename)

        if not cfg:
            msg = 'Config file not readable: Using default parameters.'
            logging.error(msg)
            return self.defaults

        settings = {}
        # Iterate over defaults keys to get each option to lookup
        for option in self.defaults:
            try:
                input_val = _get_config_value(config, self.sections, option)
                numerical = option in self.numericals.keys()
                # Some of the tools allow for cases where the user can choose from
                # many possible unlisted values for a specific option. This is assumed
                # when option is in defauls by not value_map
                in_value_map = option in self.value_map.keys()
                in_defaults = option in self.defaults.keys()
                # Might want to make this behavior more explicit.
                if in_defaults and in_value_map and not numerical:
                    value = input_val
                    msg = 'Will check value for option: {} in specific tool.'.format(option)
                    logging.debug(msg)
                else:
                    value = self._value_map_lookup(option, input_val, num=numerical)
            except (InvalidValueError, InvalidOptionError):
                msg = ('Invalid or missing entry for {}. Using default: '
                       ' {}.'.format(option, self.defaults[option]))
                logging.error(msg)
                settings[option] = self.defaults[option]
            else:
                logging.debug('parameter %s = %s is valid.', option, value)
                settings[option] = value

        return settings


    def _value_map_lookup(self, option, value, num=False):
        """Get value corresponding to the value argument in value_map.

        Args:
            value: A key to lookup in the value_map dict.
            numerical: dictionary of numerical entries and their ranges.

        Returns:
            A value obtained from value_map that is suited for the tool's
            logic. value_map is a map of user-inputted values to the values
            that are needed by the tool.

            value_map[option][value], or float(value) if num=True and the
            value is not in value_map.

        Raises:
            InvalidValueError: Value is not found in value_map dictionary. The given
            Value is invalid

        """
        if value in self.value_map[option].keys():
            return self.value_map[option][value]
        elif num:
            try:
                float_val = float(value)
                _check_range(float_val, self.numericals[option][0], self.numericals[option][1])
            except ValueError:
                raise InvalidValueError
            else:
                return float_val
        else:
            raise InvalidValueError


def _get_config_value(config, sections, option):
    """ Fetches value from ConfigParser

    A wrapper around ConfigParser.get(). This function checks
    that the config has the given section/option before calling
    config.get(). If the config does not have the option an
    InvalidOptionError is raised.

    Args:
        config: A RawConfigParser instance.
        sections: list of config sections to check for option.
        option: The parameter name to look up in the config.

    Returns:
        Parameter value for corresponding section and option.

    Raises:
    InvalidOptionError: The config is missing the given option argument.
    """
    for section in sections:
        if config.has_option(section, option):
            return ''.join(config.get(section, option).split()).lower()
    raise InvalidOptionError


def _check_range(value, lower, upper):
    """Check if lower < value < upper or lower < value if upper is 'inf'
    Args:
        value: A number whose range is to be checked against the given range
        lower: The lower limit on the range
        upper: The upper limit on the range

    Raises:
        InvalidValueError: value not in range
    """
    if upper == 'inf':
        if value >= lower:
            return
    elif lower <= value <= upper:
        return
    raise ValueError

class InvalidValueError(Exception):
    """Exception class for invalid values

    Exception for when the user enters a value that
    is not a valid option. Raise this exception when the
    user-inputted value in not in valid_options[key].
    """

class InvalidOptionError(Exception):
    """Exception class for invalid options

    Exception for when the user gives an unexpected or invlaid
    option. Raise this exception to handle user-inputted options
    that do not belong in the config or needed options that are
    missing.
    """
```

A config object is instantiated with:

1. a dictionary that represents a tools default config parameters

```
# Default configuration values for this tool. Equivalent to Default_Parameters.txt.
# When adding keys and values to this dictionary, make sure they are lower case and
# match the values to the values in the VALUE_MAP dict.
DEFAULTS = {
    'counting method' : 'templates',
    'productive only' : True,
    'resolved only' : True,
    'vj resolution' : 'gene',
    'correction' : 'BY',
    'alpha' : 0.05,
}
```

2. A value map dictionary which holds the acceptable values for each config option with each value mapped to what the tool needs to run internally.

```
# A nested dict where the outer dictionary keys are all options, and each nested
#   dictionary maps acceptable user-inputted values to the corresponding values
#   needed for the tool internally.
# When adding entries to be sure all strings are lowercase and devoid of whitespace.
# Note this dict does not account for numerical entries
VALUE_MAP = {
    'couting method' : {
        'templates' : 'templates',
        'rearrangement' : 'rearrangement'
    },
    'productive only' : {
        'true' : 'productive',
        'false' : 'nonproductive'
    },
    'resolved only' : {
        'true' : True,
        'false' : False
    },
    'vj resolution' : {
        'gene' :'gene',
        'family' : 'family',
        'allele' : 'allele'
    },
    'correction' : {
        'bh' : 'BH',
        'bonferroni' : 'bonferroni',
        'by' : 'BY',
        'fdr' : 'fdr',
        'none' : None,
    }
}
```

3. The filename of the file where the user configuration lives for a specific tool run.
4. The sections in the configuration.

```
SECTIONS = ['union', 'significance']
```

5. Dictionary of configuration options that can take on a numerical value in a specific range.

```
# configuaration settings that may be numerical
# keys: numerical options; values: tuples that embed accepted range.
NUMERICALS = {
    'alpha' : (0, 1)
}
```

A tool will then make a config instance and grab the parsed and validation settings from the config.settings attribute.

```
    configuration = config.Config(settings.OUTPUT_DIR,
                                  settings.DEFAULTS,
                                  settings.VALUE_MAP,
                                  settings.CONFIG_FILE,
                                  settings.SECTIONS,
                                  settings.NUMERICALS)

    parameters = configuration.settings
```

Each tool initially had it's own configuration checking method with nested try-except blocks checking each config option and it was a total mess. I spent a lot of time trying to think how to best represent and validate the config data to hopefully minimize code complexity in each tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General suggestions:

1. [`black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) can automatically format your code to be more idiomatic.
2. [`isort`](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort) can group and sort your imports automatically.
3. [`flake8`](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8) with a strict complexity limit will give you more hints to write idiomatic Python:

   ```
   [flake8]
   max-complexity = 4
   ignore = W503,E203
   ```

   That limit is not absolute by any means, but it's worth thinking hard whether you can keep it low whenever validation fails. For example, I'm working with a team on an application since a year now, and our complexity limit is up to 7 in only one place.
4. I would then recommend adding [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) everywhere (I'm not sure whether they work with Python 2 though) and validating them using a strict [`mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy) configuration:

   ```
   [mypy]
   check_untyped_defs = true
   disallow_untyped_defs = true
   ignore_missing_imports = true
   no_implicit_optional = true
   warn_redundant_casts = true
   warn_return_any = true
   warn_unused_ignores = true
   ```

Specific suggestions:

1. Things like pulling out `self.numericals.keys()` should not happen within a loop. You never modify it, so the result will be the same every time. Better to get this value once.
2. `allow_no_val` should probably just be called `allow_no_value`, since that's what it's used as.
3. If you put the bit about checking for the existence of the configuration file in a `main()` method the script would be easier to test. You could then pass a stream to `Config` - presumably `config.read` handles that just as well as a filename.
4. `__init__` running `_parse` is an antipattern. Typically `__init__` only does trivial things with its parameters, and relies on other methods to do the heavy lifting. Renaming `_parse` to `parse` would help in that case.
5. Boolean parameters are a code smell. For example, in the case of `_value_map_lookup` it would be easier to read if there was a separate lookup method for numbers.
6. Returning early and structuring the rest of the code accordingly can simplify some parts of the code. For example,

   ```
   if value in self.value_map[option].keys():
       return self.value_map[option][value]
   elif num:
       try:
           float_val = float(value)
           _check_range(float_val, self.numericals[option][0], self.numericals[option][1])
       except ValueError:
           raise InvalidValueError
       else:
           return float_val
   else:
       raise InvalidValueError
   ```

   could be written as

   ```
   if value in self.value_map[option].keys():
       return self.value_map[option][value]

   if not num:
       raise InvalidValueError

   try:
       float_val = float(value)
       _check_range(float_val, self.numericals[option][0], self.numericals[option][1])
       return float_val
   except ValueError:
       raise InvalidValueError
   ```
7. Why does `_get_config_value` check for an option in *every* section and return the first one? That seems to make sections pointless, because they don't matter.